# How can I flag a process from a kernel module?

Tags: c, linux, kernel-module

I have a kernel module(in c), which is working and would like to:

1. accept input from a user for a process number
2. mark that process as SIGNAL_UNKILLABLE as in [the linux source code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/sched/signal.h#L263)

> `#define SIGNAL_UNKILLABLE    0x00000040 /* for init: ignore fatal signals */`

I created a kernel module in c and searched online, but no working results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I flag a process from a kernel module?

Looking at https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0.19/A/ident/SIGNAL_UNKILLABLE, should be super normally.

```
struct task_struct *t = find_task_by_vpid(thepid);
t->signal->flags |= SIGNAL_UNKILLABLE;
```